# Python C extension with data file

Tags: python, c, distutils

I'm trying to write and install a C Extension for Python which has to load a 120MB data file.  Using distutils `package_data` argument I've got it installing the data file correctly to the same folder as the extension module.  However, the C code doesn't know how to find the data file.

I can hard code the path to the installed data file in the C extension (that works), but that's obviously not going to work on systems with different installation directories.  I'll need to install this extension both under Linux and Windows.

I've tried using `PyModule_GetFilename()` to get the path to the module, and then build the path to the datafile from that, but that function raises `SystemError: module filename missing`.  Possibly the error is because I'm trying to call it inside my module init function?

If necessary I can load the data file manually outside of module initialization, though I would much rather load the file automatically on import.

EDIT: So, I found a workaround.  I wrote an initialization function which can take the file's path as an argument.  From Python, I can access the module's `__file__` attribute and figure out the path to the data file from there.  Then, everything works if I run the initialization function in `__init__.py`.  While this works, I'm still hoping that someone out there can give me a more elegant solution, because this feels pretty backwards to me!

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a somewhat better solution on my own and thought I'd post it in case it helps anyone else.

My project consists of a package (`my_module`) with a C extension.  The installation contains `_my_extension.so`, `__init__.py`, and `datafile.dat`.  In relevant part, `__init__.py` looks like:

```
import os

def datafile_path():
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "datafile.dat")

import _my_extension
```

My C extension initialization functions looks like:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
init_my_extension(void)
{
    PyObject *m, *fileobj, *pModule, *pFunc;

    m = Py_InitModule3("_my_extension", _my_extension_methods, "A docstring");
    if (m == NULL)
        return;

    pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("my_module");
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "datafile_path");
    fileobj = PyObject_CallFunction(pFunc, NULL);
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);

    LoadDataFile(PyString_AS_STRING(fileobj));

    Py_DECREF(fileobj);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
}
```

I'll need to add some error handling obviously, and this still seems a little off, but at least it loads the data file at module initialization time, and works.  Obviously I could do much of the `datafile_path` computation in C, but since I needed to import the module anyway, and since I want cross-platform compatibility, it seemed easier to just use the `os` module.

Anyway, I'd still be happy if anyone could tell me how to do this better, so I'll leave this open, but I thought I'd put up an answer both to help anyone with the same problem in case no better answer is forthcoming, and because I thought it might clarify the problem.